# Generate an url to a telegram bot command

Tags: url, telegram-bot

I want to create a QR code than links to a telegram bot so when people scans this code they can automatically issues certain command

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Using Deep Linking you can start a Telegram bot passing an extra parameter

```
https://t.me/my_telegram_bot?start=my_action
```

The link will open the chatbot on Telegram showing the START button: the parameter `my_action` is passed to the `start` command.

As far as I know you cannot pass commands dynamically but you can use the `/start` command as entry point (the parameter will define what to do).